# JSOM and authentication

Tags: jsom

I am developing an Outlook Addin (JavaScript). I need to also use JSOM to connect to OneDrive for Business in that addin to upload a file. I don't know how to authenticate to use JSOM. Is there any article that can help me to authenticate from an Office Addin? Thanks

Comment: follow the link. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering, but I have read that the MSAL library is not suitable for Sharepoint ONline. Like if when I get the token from MSAL then I will not be able to perform SP Online REST API calls.
For example
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/get-valid-auth-token-from-MSAL-for-SP-Online/m-p/354239

Thanks